# Ionic React with SignalR Redis Backplane

Tags: reactjs, kubernetes, ionic-framework, signalr, traefik

We were able to successfully setup a **React Web App** using **ASP Net Core 6** + **SignalR** with **Redis Backplane**.

```
            services.AddSignalR(hubOptions => { hubOptions.EnableDetailedErrors = true; })
                .AddStackExchangeRedis(appSettings.RedisConnectionString, options => {
                    options.Configuration.ChannelPrefix = appSettings.RedisPrefix;
                });
```

We are using **Kubernetes** + **Traefik** with the following **IngressRoute** configuration to ensure that the **React Web Application** maintains connection to one of the servers per session.

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: routes
  namespace: default
spec:
  entryPoints:
  - websecure
  routes:
  - kind: Rule
    match: Host(`canary-api.app.com`)
    services:
    - kind: Service
      name: app-server-canary
      namespace: default
      passHostHeader: true
      sticky:
        cookie:
          httpOnly: true
          name: "traefik_sticky"
      port: 80
  tls:
    store:
      name: default
```

After these changes, the **SignalR** based **Chat System** on our **React Web App** works but the **Ionic React Build** of the same application for **Mobile Release** does not work. Is there something that needs to be done on the **React Ionic Build** to ensure that it respects the same sticky sessions as the regular **React Web App** does?

We're confident the server side is okay because the statically served **React Web App** works fine. It seems like we just missed some configuration in the config xml for **React Ionic Build** but we're not sure at this point.